# Is it possible to import External data into Tradingview?

Tags: editor, pine-script

Maybe its a silly question, but i  wanted it to be more of a discussion.

Is it possible to actually get external data into pine editor or tradingview from own scripts outside of trading view.
And if so how would i do it.

Is tradingview considering making this possible or is it off limits, i imagine it must be expensive to do.
But isnt this something us pine editor programmers want?
Whats your opinion?

Best regards.

Mathias.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible on any way. It is unsure if it ever will be. Sadly, we will know when we know. I patiently await with you.

Cheers.

Comment: Allright, yes we must wait in patience then, and hope for the best. 
Thanks.